# Make recorded voice sound like specific tenor / actor?

Tags: software-rec, video-editing, audacity, audio-processing

This might seem unusual but I need to edit an audio file(wav) that is saying some sentences for a presentation and make it sound like a certain tenor that I can find audio samples in the Internet.

I have basic knowledge of Audacity and Goldwave.

Any ideas of how to achieve this? And of course what software tools do I need?

Comment: *> make it sound like a certain tenor* – how, specifically? Please be more precise with what you want, maybe find an example of the effect you need.

Comment: Check the top answer in [this thread](http://superuser.com/questions/386695/how-to-slow-down-audio-files) for some possibly useful information for audacity

Comment: This is an old post, but software is finally catching up.  See Adobe Photoshop for Audio: http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/11/adobe-voco-photoshop-for-audio-speech-editing/